# Improper integral: $\int_1^\infty\frac{\sin(\sqrt{x})}{\sqrt{x}}dx $.

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals, mathematica

mathematica is reporting that the improper integral $\int_1^\infty\frac{\sin(\sqrt{x})}{\sqrt{x}}dx $ coverges to $2\cos(1)$. However, when I try to confirm this by actually integrating it using u-substitution, I end up with $-2\lim\limits_{n=1}^\infty\left(\cos n - \cos 1\right)$. I am thinking we cannot determine the first limit here.(oscillation). Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: $u=\sqrt{x}, du = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}dx$

Comment: the OP tried this already.

Comment: The first limit doesn't exist

Comment: This bug (nice catch!) might be worth posting to http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/ . At least one SE user here and there, @daniel-lichtblau is a Wolfram employee - there are probably others - and might pass it on to the developers.

Comment: What is interesting is that, if we first change variable $x=u^2$ and ask for integration, the answer from WA  is *the integral does not converge* instead of the stupid $2\cos(1)$.

Comment: The Mathematica Question is here if you are interested: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/106162/why-does-mathematica-report-that-int-1-infty-frac-sin-sqrtx-sqrtxdx

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OP, you are correct, $$\int_1^n\frac{\sin \sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{x}}dx=-2\cos\sqrt{n}+2\cos 1$$
Hence the improper integral is $$\int_1^\infty\frac{\sin \sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{x}}dx=\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_1^n\frac{\sin \sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{x}}dx=\lim_{n\to\infty}-2\cos\sqrt{n}+2\cos 1$$
And the latter limit does not exist.  Your computer algebra system (mathematica) is giving an incorrect answer.  Alpha gives the same incorrect answer, probably because it's got mathematica under the hood.

Comment: Perhaps, mathematica is choosing something like $ (2\pi n +\pi/2)^2 $ as sequence tending to infinity? (sorry for my previous - incorrect - comment)